# Laptop keeps shutting down suddenly

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I have Ubuntu 12 32 bits installed on my Emachines E728, and everytime I turn it in on and start using it it shuts down suddenly without a warning. I thought it's a heat problem but it seems like it's not. 
Another thing that happens is that when I put down the laptops screen, or try to put it into sleep mode, it never gets out of it (actually, I doubt it's even going to sleep mode, because the power light stays on). So I think it's a driver problem (because I actually didn't install ubuntu, I just backed up an image file which was created on a different computer, on a Desktop HP computer to be more accurate)

So I thought I should update my driver, but each time I click on Additional Drivers, the computer gets off again. What can I do about it ? I really need this image, I don't want to install a new one.

Comment: What point of boot process does it get to ? what's the output of `dmesg` command in terminal (try using Ctrl+Alt+F2 to access it )?How did you back up your image ?

Comment: With Ubuntu, you can't just move the installation to another computer like you can with Windows. Get the 12.04 (or 12.10, depending on what you have) 32-bit ISO from ubuntu.com, burn it to a CD or USB stick and reinstall Ubuntu. This should fix driver problems and will also keep your data.

Comment: @Serg I don't get your question, it boots normally, the gui works, but while I'm working it suddenly turns off. I wasn't the one who backed up the image, it was my teacher, I think he used Seagate Acronis, and I restored it with Acronis True Image since my HDD is not Seagate, but that shouldn't be the problem, right ?

Comment: @Zacharee1 You are sure I wouldn't lose my data ? there are some packages that I don't want to lose

Comment: You won't. It tells you so.

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy Ubuntu should be pretty good at adjusting to different hardware; Zacharee1 is wrong, Windows is more cringy to hardware changes. I've known of users who moved hard drives with Ubuntu to other computers when their  original laptops died, and they had no problem. As for my question this is what I mean: next time your unexpected shutdown happens, boot the system again, and open command line with Ctrl + Alt +T, then run this command `dmesg > dmesg-output.txt` . Now you should have a file in your home folder dmesg-output.txt. Post that on pastebin.com, and link to your question.

Comment: @serg I'm taking Ubuntu's transfer problems from at least three other cases on this site of people moving their installation to a completely new computer and having problems. The shutdown follows the idea of Ubuntu having this trouble, since it would include changing motherboards and thus having different supported power states and options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is possible to move an installation from one computer to another**, but there are limitations to what you can do if you want a truly portable OS.  E.g. no proprietary modules, no hardware-dependant configurations (E.g. fans / sensors, keyboards, hard disks, …)

So if the original OS wasn't installed with portability in mind, moving it over to another computer is going to be *much more difficult* and will *take much more time* then:

- taking a back-up of your current data
- wipe the system partition (if the system partition and the data partition are mixed into 1 single partition, this will also wipe the data)
- re-install the OS, letting it auto-detect your specific configuration
- restore the data
- re-install the applications you need

Comment: installing the applications I need was my main problem, that's why I needed to use an image created by my teacher...

Comment: Then you're not going to find an answer here...  On Ask Ubuntu the answers have to be specific, not broad.  Yours is bound to be closed as "too broad to be able to answer here"  I needs extended discussion, logs, and then removing of proprietary modules, installing other modules, ...  You're looking at a week of intensive work.  That's not what Ask Ubuntu is about...